# Why aren't chia seeds considered to be kitniyot?

Tags: food, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

[According to the OU](https://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/food-items/kitniyot-list/), plain unground chia seeds are not kitniyot. Given that they're almost indistinguishable from poppy seeds, which are considered to be kitniyot, I'm puzzled as to why not.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why one might have thought they should be kitniyot?

Comment: They're almost indistinguishable from poppy seeds.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Please edit your comment into the question to make it self-standing.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that we don't add new food to the traditional list of *kitniot* (which is often quoted in the context of quinoa). You will likely find [this article](https://ohr.edu/5390) by R Spitz enlightening. I am not familiar enough with chia seeds to see how they match the criteria for *kitniot* but you might.

Comment: A quick search shows that chia seeds were not used as food in Europe until the very late 20th century. Much of the basis of Kitniyos, as I understand it, is not confusion between items but inadvertent mixing due to packaging - e.g., reusing the same grain sacks for corn and wheat. But if chia was a really unusual item it would not have been (certainly not hundreds of years ago) packed in the same sacks as wheat in Europe - because it basically did not exist in Europe.